# Commitment scheme to share money

Tags: reference-request, zero-knowledge-proofs, commitments

I have such problem: party $X$ has an amount of money $M$, which it needs to share with $n$ other parties. Every week the amount of money is different. 
Let say not, that I am a party A, which is one of those $n$ parties which are waiting for their money from $X$. Do you maybe know any protocol or commitment schema, which allow $A$ to be sure that he received exactly $\frac{M}{n}$ every single week, without knowing $n$ and $M$?
I would be very grateful for any suggestions with the references to any bibliography.

Comment: How do you define "money"?

Comment: As an integer value, we can assume that $M$ is divided by $n$, I think it will not make any difference.

Comment: If A knows he received $x$ dollars, and knows $M$, and knows $x=M/n$, then A can compute $n$. The only way for A to know $M$ and know he received exactly $M/n$ dollars and not know $n$ is if A doesn't know how much money he actually got in dollars, but that's an unlikely scenario.

Comment: @cpast Yes, of course you are right, my bad. But what if suppose $A$ doesn't know M?